# How to get selected month's last date in C#.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a drop down list  for selecting the month in `.aspx` page. I have  to get last date of the selected month  in `.aspx.cs` page. (some months have 30 days and some have 31 days)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 24):

There's no need for custom calculations.

Use the [`System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(yearNum, monthNum)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) method to find out the number of days in any given month (which is also the last day).

It's as simple as:

```
//Get days in month 2 (Feb) of year 2011. Returns 28.
int daysInFeb2011 = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2011, 2);
```

---

The MSDN documentation provides a more thorough and descriptive sample:

```
        const int July = 7;
        const int Feb = 2;

        // daysInJuly gets 31.
        int daysInJuly = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(2001, July);

        // daysInFeb gets 28 because the year 1998 was not a leap year.
        int daysInFeb = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(1998, Feb);

        // daysInFebLeap gets 29 because the year 1996 was a leap year.
        int daysInFebLeap = System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(1996, Feb);
```