# How to get total number of days in a month based on year?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a drop down lists for selecting the month and year in .aspx page. I have to get last date of the selected month of particular selected year in .aspx.cs page. (some months have 30 days and some have 31 days)

How can I do this?

Regards,

N.SRIRAM

Comment: You asked this extremely similar question less than an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744660/how-to-get-selected-months-last-date-in-c-net If this is the same issue, please *edit* that question to add more information.

Answer (score 12):

You can use:

System.DateTime.DaysInMonth(int year, int month)

Answer (score 5):

[System.DateTime.DaysInMonth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) this should help you.